# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <package name>.activity.BaseActivity.onResume

Tags: android, exception, android-fragmentactivity

Recently I sometimes got this exception when CameraActivity called onResume().

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to resume activity {<pacakge name>/<package name>.activity.record.CameraActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3586)
......
Caused by:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1669)
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1618)
 android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:5516)
 android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:6203)
 android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1307)
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:485)
 <package name>.activity.BaseActivity.onResume(BaseActivity.java:207)
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1279)
 android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7017)
 android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3561)
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1618)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

public abstract class BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIsResuming = true;
        mAnchorPoint = null;
    }
}
```

I want to know the reason why the system above android 7.0 will throw such exception sometimes. I checked some relative reference material but nothing got.

**Note: Only occurs on android 7.0+**

Comment: Show CameraActivity code